# fadein navbar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for some help with getting my fade in navigation bar to work. 
I'm using the code below, and everything works on jsfiddle. But i can't get it to work in my code. I think that there might be a problem with my links:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){ <br>
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('#naw').offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('#naw').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                } else {
                        $('#naw').css({position: 'static', top: '100px'});
                }
        });
  });

    </script>
```

this is the working jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/uFq2k/1123/

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

add this to the navbar

```
display: none;
```

and this to the scroll javascript

```
$(".navbar").fadeIn(500);
```